# mysqldump: Error 1053: Server shutdown in progress when dumping table

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to dump 13GB database , while doing that I'm encountering following error.
Here is the dump statment

```
mysqldump -u user_db -p resolve_production > resolve_production.sql
```

mysqldump: Error 1053: Server shutdown in progress when dumping table `audits` at row: 10506716

Comment: In my case, it was caused by too big query - that was crashing my DB process.
Private DB can log these issues in file like "slow-query.log" in it's FTP/SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Server was shutdown or restated when the backup start, and your backup is not complete, i recommend you to dump your file again. the Backup can be corrupted or incomplete.